# How to remove duplicate lines without sorting and only matching nth colum

Tags: awk, duplicates

Hi I am trying to remove "duplicate" lines from a file but I want to maintain the file order and I dont want to match the entire line, just the second column.

Example

```
23 google.com 345 432 3
543 google.com d9 0ds aa
8 amazon.com 820 2 2
45 google.com 80a s0d e
32 yahoo.com wqq 33 234
```

Would become

```
23 google.com 345 432 3
8 amazon.com 820 2 2
32 yahoo.com wqq 33 234
```

I know how to `sort -u -o file` but that matches the enitre line and it reorders the file. I saw this `awk '!seen[$0]++' file` which will avoid the sorting but it still matches the entire line.

Anyone know if this can be done?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The awk solution can be modified to match only the second column:

```
awk '!seen[$2]++' file
```

Comment: Ok so the 0 meant entire line and the 2 means the 2nd column. Thanks!

Comment: That's correct. The default field separator (`FS`) is typically a whitespace (space, multiple spaces, tab(s), and so on). With `-F`, you can even split columns with different delimiter e.g., `echo "hello+world" | awk -F"+" '{print $2}'` would print `world`.

Answer (score 1):

Try just matching the 2nd column:

```
awk '!seen[$2]++'
```